# How to turn off deleting precision in column of number type?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have table xx with column amount. It's number type without set precision.

When I put data 10.00, in database I have 10.
When I put data 10.01 in database I have correct value 10.01

How can I fix it to have value with the precision I have given ?

Comment: `10.00` has no precision in the sense that is just 10. If you want to show it with trailing zeros, you need to apply a `to_char` function in a select statement or change the format in whatever tool you are using. You have to understand the difference between how the numbers are stored and how you can visualized them

Answer (score 3):

The precision is correct - 10.00 and 10 are the same, identical value.  It is just that the tool you are using to view the data is formatting 10.00 as 10.  In tools like SQL Plus, SQL Developer you can specify a different display format like this:

```
column n format 999.99

select 10.00 n from dual;

    N
-----
10.00
```

Or you can format explicitly:

```
select to_char(n, '999.99') from mytable;
```